# False entry in field to get past validation

Tags: validation

How can I validate if the user has entered the same char multiple times to get a false valid entry in a field.
ie: 11111111111

Comment: refer this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17793962/writing-a-regex-to-detect-repeat-characters

Comment: Thanks Santanu - great help (might have to do this in Apex) but was hoping to add to a validation rule.  Expecting that it cannot be done.

Comment: validation rule supports regex

Comment: That link pretty much has your answer, but if you want to prevent the input from being *all* the same character (rather than just having them all the same at the end), you should add the front line anchor as well: `'^(.)(?>\\1+)$'`

Comment: But then they would just do 1111112 or 12121212. Training and discipline issue really. Amazing how much time users read error and spend time to get around them but for real errors they act like the are stumped lol

Comment: agreed Eric - the effort ppl will spend to get around things amazes me.  I have done an analysis of the current data and the majority of times ppl just use the same character so if we can stop that it will go towards cleaner input. A little is better than nothing

Answer (score 4):

Something like `REGEX(Name, ".*(.)\\1{2,}.*")` could be used to prevent 3 or more of the same character. Let's break this validation rule down:

- `.*` match any characters (even none at all).
- `(.)` match any specific character, and remember it as "capture group 1."
- `\\1` match "capture group 1."
- `{2,}` match two or more of the same pattern.

Of course, 3 might be legitimate for some fields (e.g. phone could reasonably have 888, 000, or some other 3 repeating characters), but the basic principle remains the same. You'll need to check each field you want to validate individually.